# What is an adequate backup strategy for Debian system with a simple database?

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I would like to know a suitable backup strategy for a small business running a simple database. The whole system operates from a single local computer with one internal hard disk. I have already looked into some backups utilities such as `rsync` and `dump` but wasn't sure which is more appropriate for this type of scenario.

As a specific example, I wish to understand whether a backup utility like `rsync` is suitable for copying data from a database, MySQL or not, and storing into a external hard drive.

Comment: What sort of database? What sort of backup? There is not enough information here to answer...

Comment: MYSQL Database/simple database, and just to backup essential data such as personal information for a business.

Comment: Please add that detail to your question. Also include detail about the destination (remote/local, filesystem, etc)...

Comment: I simply wish to understand wether a backup utility like rsync is suitable for copying data from a database, MySQL or not, and storing into a external hard drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked,

> whether a backup utility like rsync is suitable for copying data from a database, MySQL or not

The answer here is an emphatic "No!".

Unless you are prepared to switch off MySQL while you perform an `rsync`-based backup you will almost certainly end up with a corrupted database on your backup. (The live system would remain unaffected and working correctly.) The reason for this is that the database system can and will update different parts of different files at different times. `rsync` blithely ignores this and copies the files as it finds them.

As an example, consider two interrelated files A and B. A gets copied with `rsync`. While that's going on B is updated by the database system. Now the database system applies related updates to A but `rsync` has finished with A and is starting on B. The backup now contains two "valid" files A and B but they are out of sync with respect to each other.

To backup a database you need to use tool that understands the database system. MySQL includes such tools in the package and you should use those to backup the database. (You can then copy the resulting database backups to your external disk drive using `rsync` or any other other preferred utility.)

Comment: It's possible, execute the SQL command `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` and leave the mysql client running. During this time the table data files are consistent and can be copied. However any attempts to update records during this time will block, waiting for the lock. Terminate the mysql client to release the lock after copying the files. This is the recommended way of setting replication, BTW. Another way is to use a filesystem with snapshot capability, that means you only need the read lock during the time to make the snapshot.

Comment: @wurtel thank you. I wasn't aware that the `FLUSH...` would leave the files in a safe configuration. A snapshot filesystem would be good, but without reference to it in the question I assumed one wouldn't be available

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, no. Databases must be backed up with purpose-built utilities in order to ensure a consistent (i.e., no half-committed transactions, etc.) backup. This is actually true of any file that's being written while you're trying to copy it—it's very hard to get a consistent backup without assistance from the program writing the data.

(So, if you shut down MySQL, then you could use rsync. But people normally want to keep their databases up.)

There are several available for MySQL, from `mysqldump` to Percona's XtraBackup. Both of those are available in Jessie (and for Wheezy as well, though xtrabackup might require adding a 3rd-party repository).